# Does the following infinite series converge?? (Leibnitz)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5n+1}}\right)
$$

Will someone please help me validate my way?

After moving to a common denominator, and multiplying by the "conjugate", we obtain the series:
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left( \frac{n}{ \sqrt{5n+1} \sqrt{4n+1} (\sqrt{4n+1}+\sqrt{5n+1}) } \right)
$$

as for the absolute convergence: we can use limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^{0.5}}$ to obtain the series diverges. As for convergence- this is a Leibnitz series, so it converges.

Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: It is clear that the terms go to $0$ in absolute value. You have not verified explicily that the terms decrease in absolute value.  All the rest is fine.

Comment: Yes it does absolutely diverge. For the convergence you just have to show that 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5n+1}}$ tends to zero (obvious) and that it is definitively decreasing for $n\rightarrow +\infty$. Have you done that?

Comment: I can show it is decreasing by moving to a function and differentiating, right?

Comment: By the way, it is [Leibniz](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizSeries.html), not "Leibnitz".

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\left( { - 1} \right)^n } \frac{1}
{{\sqrt {4n + 1} }}
$$
is convergent by Leibniz. The same is true for
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\left( { - 1} \right)^n } \frac{1}
{{\sqrt {5n + 1} }}
$$
thus the given series is convergent because is the difference of two convergent series.